# (Grails plugin) Spring Security Single Signout

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-cas

I'm trying to understand how Spring Security handles Single Signout.  I'm using a CAS server with multiple Grails apps.  Here is my scenario:

App #1 & Login

1. User navigates to Grails app #1.
2. app #1 has no authentication data for the User, and checks the CAS server.  The CAS server has no cookie data for the User, so CAS prompts the User to login.
3. User logs in to CAS and gets a valid ticket.  User is redirected back to the app #1 URL from step 1.
4. In the first request after authentication, app #1 loads the CAS ticket into its SecurityContextHolder.  Subsequent requests use the ticket data to verify the user is authenticated.

App #2 & Logout

1. User navigates to Grails app #2.
2. app #2 has no authentication data for the User, and checks the CAS server.  The CAS server has cookie data for the User and uses this data to authenticate the User.
3. In the first request after authentication, app #2 loads the CAS ticket into its SecurityContextHolder.  Subsequent requests use the ticket data to verify the user is authenticated.

Logout

1. User logs out of app #2 by hitting app #2's logout page.  app #2 no longer has User data stored in SecurityContextHolder.
2. User is redirected to the CAS server logout page.  CAS no longer has a valid ticket for the User.
3. Subsequent (protected) requests to app #2 will redirect the User to the CAS login page.
4. **Because app #1 still has CAS ticket data in its SecurityContextHolder, subsequent (protected) requests to app #1 will not redirect the user to login.  The context must be cleared or expire somehow.**

**How am I supposed to keep the User from accessing protected URLs in app #1 ? Is there an expiration date I can set for the SecurityContextHolder ?**